# array variable available sitewide in a custom configuration file - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to store an array in a config file `config/project_specific.php

```
<?php

return [
    'sluggable_models1' => 'test_value', // works
    'sluggable_models2' => ['features','packages'], // throws error
];
```

I call this value by `$models = config('project_specific.sluggable_models')` in my controller

### problem

as long as the variable is a string, it works. When the value is an array type, i get this error `ErrorException in helpers.php line 515: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: \resources\views\starter\admin\dashboard_admintools.blade.php)`

### to do

how I can store a sitewide accessible array in my Laravel 5.3 app?
Not necesarily a config file, but I prefer to avoid a DB-fed solution.

Comment: The error seems to indicate the array is making it to your view just fine but you are trying to print the variable in your blade template vs. looping over it. Your config file is fine...I routinely have arrays with multiple sub arrays in my config files. Can you add your view code?

Comment: That was so obvious. Thank you! Whether you upgrade your hint to an answer, it's up to you.

Comment: no problem! Sometimes it takes a fresh set eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to indicate the array is making it to your view just fine but you are trying to print the variable in your blade template vs. looping over it.

{{ }} is essentially the same as echo but it tries to escape the string using htmlentities(), hence the error.